# How to set the width of this vega lite chart(tried width: 'container' but no use)

Tags: vega-lite, vega

Trying to plot the vega lite graph similar to [grouped bar chart](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_grouped.html), but facing some issue related to the size.

Could you please help me to understand where it is failing ?

Referred this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/vega-bar-chart/283578 article to create the below sample code

Sharing sample code used for [this](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQmAE5JZEAGZsVCNAG1Q2wQBMDIHCrhQaEdvKVWoSQYJABdAL7ulJpJhRUUFkkBDg0ZSQmQXClYhcGOAgDUCgrfzgzdAAmAAZs7P5cgEYigHZFEAgGFWIaeMEAfWqoKCTk1Fylatr6l0bNJBoYrK6QOrtMZoZW9rQxiboBoZH5pRw4WRMaWTI0YvWnW3s1kCcXN06lOBUVHXnPBVT0zEyIvIKi0uLcyp66hrTWYQDpjf59JqDYZvK7jY5TFptEGnRZTKGrWEbLY7PaoA4WI52OSnc6uU43O4qB5PEBpOAZLIgD6FEr8YrFP41AH9RFzWHgwHomELeFApGguKioWjdabba7U6WazHYmw0mXMYU+6dR7PemvRnMr5s7Kc3qA3nI-lciHLaEyuGTMV8kVO6WKuU4tDZQ7KonyNXWC7k27a3K62kvGFM-Is74AZjN3KalolVRtgpWwslTtTKKlWYdWPluPxSps-pJQbJsK1VJ1NLpDPeseNxQALEnbXnreb+u7YajnVbXUsB2Ni17UPHfRWToHnDXNaH6+HG1HDa3WcUKt0MzyZuLTgL+4X87nDy6c2Oz5jPQrUAAOWcqgNjdUhynUvXNnJb76Pl2FqXiOe59pCt6jgiIEdPiQ7jrK2IPj6BJ+vO77Vhq1wrt+kb6tGRrbgAnEBB7AmmJ4Qfa55LD2UF2hiE73riKHlq+VaLlhIB1rhTYGi2nysnkpEpjBx77lRjHXtB5E0WikGISW+wvpWC7BrWOENj+-F-oJpTZByYHJsOFESQx2aOrRYmDgW1F3khuJiCp6GOJhn7asUEZ8QR-78NknZGd21lgmZCGWTJR42W6CkWMx3rOaqGGce59bZF5G4CXGfliCJJnieB5kOkOdHSYVHoOWgREJW+rnJRpX6oGl674Zuel+bu6YFSVnXGWFxXWSh8ExZOyHVcpZxuXi2ENWu2k+W12SAYFwGyXiuQhQVfWij2cG2RiZZxZihIuRNdXLjN6UtZlRRxrlO3rctp52fRPYzuFZX2UpjVjVNp3qfiPF4pdv4xoJLKmo9omrWIG29beMOld1Q12axh1lsdiW1ep50ecDOmg+DRSJpDeW9nDdk-C91m7dFz2KVOE4YwG+Ifr9gPxnj82E7kAU9UFq2UyTW0XgLpVhSNuJvWxqks5NAOabNeEg4RLIdZRpOw7awtWat9Hi4drFMxx2PTWGnOtdzS18ytkWC9bT1Se9SN7TCqMVd9qFzpjf1Lqbq7m9d+RFCRJPder2sRVe736+76Nod7rM4-7zXK1uhQ-HdwVCzF-W62Lw2HWUP1JSb3Gae2Ae6YT7KZ3n9uSRZue2-nKP0w+Pw-bLdXyxdKf4yrbK8+rYehTn23Uy3jsS4qRu-azPfahzfdczdbI5aH1MPfXH1U6L0cF+7jPx8zWM1gvydzRbq-FAAbLXkWa5mFNb03fJOfvdlF7F7vtsXlCPvGQBQDgHAN-j7S459eIZSrtfK2w9rJiDKJQDsi1EEoMfGgsB4dbztmyP-TBqCyjoLEGA1+Vpnwf32gdd2FDpbzi7v9P2UCrowKDgUe+fJ2wSC4TwkhfDeHZzsiQyg-DRG8NIePVaX9kYYiqt-L6xRDbH3mJQG+p8IFMLWhGeBq1HyPwdq7XekV34yJhFLQ6b1AZHy9m+SgRDcEYPsYQjsb155KG8lfNhnZtFmR7Nkd+2DP4mMkZFN6pisjUK+ihQGccbHjTcUrfuadsogB8V1LO28I4a0nhZae9UPLF3UacDxgd4xFG8TSHRD9BGOzIWmcJ5UvpJ3ip7dialfaJJXrkMpuQSJpOMiPTaY8RbVMobkw6YCrGFPAcU6BBMiZsl+P0-mkUAGUBARswBWDR4Uxvqom+BzDlHMORIkZnCclZDdl9SZmklFxLnnLdxczCJlJrssm2UdAm1JCVHBpn0pyQN+nQhOk0xglNYe2PySzKm+IyV8xuPzQJjKLGjTRsS2klw6eC+ZPM-IcneWRUZ8KiqIvqS7FFsdNFS1npiri2LCKQv8akmF6S67Erktk5FjSpzRNudMxOTyWE4sZXfAlUMiU7O+WcpFfymLuy-oDd+wKaozNhPSrcjKKhis5eyqKOtRmyrbpLTR1iMVFLVc8jVflALasGeTKV+rfnku5Q+ORMT+WgsFanQSjK+ksoGXCyVCLpVktplPCxJqPVnS9UkwSYgbrMtAFUz5QaSUho5THBRkbWmqVpbMoVhF4080TdvO1WthmOplc6-5D5LEKyjaXdVcaiiiv9SslNQy6ZOwyYa+RU41Flxmg2rFlrm29JLcmpFuqjFOrDeM92Bk0VKppeasFo6WTxuKImW1gbO0OsjlWudWRzGx3fu6nNJ0BWdM8Zu1tSbYUCy3tOxGPbq2RJ5W6zSy7lHtLpeuoom6tVto+VO1NHLnZHpdSxZpqBv33LzRagtW5N02uA4Sjt9rg2VtDTeLteT4xiBvjB+MuQMHDr-Uh5txQ-X3tZRKvdWGD04fknhtGN9CPZuVcbEdlGN1QonQ++jmG03YYzQfLNg6wzkfzd6vjBkBN0Yw+WrtdSxOsZ-pxldqq128YA35U0O62Vgb1UxtT4b3Z1qHRekF0br2B3jdkbdaHxVKafvuzlva8mAtNbm1dMaukOe8V4JQyAVAAGs0CgEwAATw2BEJgSAqRKEwGwNgghMA0BwGgVQiRHjcVkFANgX1UhpYYAgAMRgaBwFMBEEpyWaBhAAKqyDoBEaL9JdByHoH4V4lQYtxfQDoeULhKjwCQCYG4kWQCCCiNVgA8ioKrshMDxbYNgNgeglAzaYNVgAgrsGIaAiNbdm4IAACuNr6JGTs7cELt4QZAAzTbgJoFbeWMuYEO+gAAKg1uAAACAASuoMgsQqg4CQDYZCa4QAAA8puaCqzV9AYW4DRb67F8Ig2VDDbcEoJAsPbBoFkAwVweX0dBBAIj6rjIGiJAxwNkAABHBg6gPv+HqGDj7X2QAADUEhwAABQAFIACUlQkBkDIFYCgvXUAk9cEobQuh-AREoNkTQzLaRpe1JVmnERUfo+S5jiIsgNs7BG90RcWPQBqF2Fj-QIAADEN8yhiGo8TZ3zhHyPhvhyYLyg6A87OzcZXyACsA4ALJwFUDQJElQYig62FNnQS2VvoBS1l9Yl2eVjG29VgAorDywEQGA4A2CoQXPWyuUHz4IcXnhG-uLkIj3EoACdE8p9LmgWRBiCAgHAPLdQ4AAHcpsQFUGwVHERVDqAgBDqwy3UmN6AA)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "transform": [
        {`enter code here`
            "fold": [
                "precision",
                "recall"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "name": "table",
        "values": [
            {
                "created": "2022-01-07",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-10",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-11",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-12",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 2,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-13",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-14",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 3,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-17",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 8,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-18",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 1,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 2,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-19",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 2,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-20",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-21",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 5,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 1
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-24",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 2,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 2
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-25",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 9,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 2
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-27",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 2,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 2,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-01-28",
                "survival_success": 100,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 1,
                "visit_failed": 1,
                "pending": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-01",
                "survival_success": 100,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 3,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 2,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 1
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-02",
                "survival_success": 50,
                "survival_failed": 50,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 2,
                "pending": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 1
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-03",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 100,
                "visit_success": 1,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 0,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 3
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-04",
                "survival_success": 100,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 1,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 3,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-07",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 2,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-08",
                "survival_success": 100,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 2,
                "pending": 2,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-09",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-10",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 7,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "error": 4
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-11",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 1,
                "visit_failed": 2,
                "pending": 10,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-14",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 1,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 0,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 3
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-15",
                "survival_success": 100,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 1,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 0,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-16",
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 100,
                "visit_success": 5,
                "visit_failed": 7,
                "pending": 4,
                "precision": 0.8333333333333334,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-18",
                "survival_success": 57.14285714285714,
                "survival_failed": 42.857142857142854,
                "visit_success": 8,
                "visit_failed": 11,
                "pending": 8,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 0
            },
            {
                "created": "2022-02-22",
                "survival_success": 45.45454545454545,
                "survival_failed": 54.54545454545454,
                "visit_success": 7,
                "visit_failed": 9,
                "pending": 12,
                "precision": 0.6,
                "recall": 1,
                "error": 10
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 80,
                "survival_failed": 20,
                "visit_success": 5,
                "visit_failed": 3,
                "pending": 3,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0.7142857142857143,
                "recall": 1,
                "created": "2022-02-24"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 25,
                "survival_failed": 75,
                "visit_success": 3,
                "visit_failed": 1,
                "pending": 2,
                "error": 1,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "created": "2022-02-25"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 0,
                "error": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-03-04"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 0,
                "error": 2,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-03-09"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 4,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-03-10"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 83.33333333333334,
                "survival_failed": 16.666666666666664,
                "visit_success": 4,
                "visit_failed": 2,
                "pending": 4,
                "error": 2,
                "precision": 1,
                "recall": 1,
                "created": "2022-03-11"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "error": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-04-20"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "error": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-04-21"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "error": 3,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-04-25"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 2,
                "error": 2,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-04-26"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 7,
                "error": 5,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-04-27"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 3,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-04-28"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 9,
                "error": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-04-29"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 3,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-02"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-04"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 3,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-06"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 6,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-09"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 21,
                "error": 15,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-13"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 3,
                "pending": 15,
                "error": 1,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-16"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 100,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 1,
                "pending": 29,
                "error": 5,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-17"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 20,
                "error": 5,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-18"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 3560,
                "error": 3085,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-19"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1656,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-20"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-21"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 4,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-22"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 3,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-23"
            },
            {
                "survival_success": 0,
                "survival_failed": 0,
                "visit_success": 0,
                "visit_failed": 0,
                "pending": 1,
                "error": 0,
                "precision": 0,
                "recall": 0,
                "created": "2022-05-24"
            }
        ]
    },
    "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "tooltip": true
    },
    "encoding": {
        "column": {
            "field": "created",
            "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
            "type": "ordinal",
            "header": {
                "labelOrient": "bottom",
                "labelAngle": 60,
                "labelPadding": 30,
                "labelAlign": "left"
            },
            "title": "Time Range",
            "spacing": 20
        },
        "x": {
            "field": "key",
            "type": "ordinal",
            "axis": null
        },
        "y": {
            "field": "value",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "title": "Value(%)",
            "aggregate": null,
            "format": ".2f"
        },
        "color": {
            "field": "key",
            "type": "nominal",
            "scale": {
                "range": [
                    "#675193",
                    "#ca8861"
                ]
            },
            "title": "Performance Metrices",
            "legend": {
                "orient": "top",
                "padding": 20,
                "labelExpr": "upper(datum.label)"
            }
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "axis": {
            "grid": false
        },
        "view": {
            "stroke": "transparent"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of discrete domain, rather than specifying width for the whole chart, you need to specify [width of each bar instead](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html#specifying-width-and-height-per-discrete-step):

```json
"width": {"step": 5},
```

Then whole width of the chart would be **number_of_bars * bar_width**

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQmAE5JZEAGZsVCNAG1Q2wQBMDIHCrhQaEdvKVWoSQYJABdAL7ulAdxom9GigEJhwOGhinkomSJgoqKCySAhwaMpITIJpSsQuDHAQBqBQVnFwZugATAAMVVX8NQCMjQDsiiAQDCrENHmCAPpdUFCFRag1Sl09fS4Dmkg02ZWTIL12mEMMI2Noq+t084vLe0o4cLImNLJkaE1nTrb2pyBOLm4TSnAqKjp70SUymFKiBavVGi0mjUOtNev0tjsIONVrDZoMFksKi8DpthqMkdinpsMSdPhYLlcbncHtYnnIXm9XC9vr8VP8FIC4OUQWCGs1+E0mjDunC5njdmTUfCSViyTiEfjkbkiUdMSszhTrrcyZZaXZ6WTGR9Viy-hMASBSlzgeleRCBVVhTN4eKCZKRWjVaT9irXUq1iqZeryZctWgqjSbPr5IbrO9mT8zTULVbuba6nzIQBmJ2iwZ+l5SuZBwkbBUSn1lks6zVU1D3CyPaMMuNMsmmtnmjmWoGy0EZ+1NAAsuc9BfdzuLx1llcO49nxOnwfOobrWcjdJjqyNCdZ7M5aeqA-5TXaUw9Lu2isLF6natLc6vFeVVaXLxXlO1AA4N83Y842xNRNO2TbtUxtI9wRPL9R0vRF-SLdE3zlX0nzdBt5WrVYPzDVAI0bPVnn-eN22A-ce2tPs7RPABOWCxTQhDbyQ+8ULLecX0OLCNVXbV8N1KMiO3VtjS+MiuwPCD+yglpano-NGJvScWO9TjcUUtiuOQ7Da21BsBM3FsANEkAO3I8CqOPWShXPZTyzdFFmK9Gc1Ps-1MO0njP0iX8hMcETdzNJoU17HkrP4KoR1svM3KUmLuIDdiNIXZzl108NfINYTjMCzsqhCyiwpkiKxHk2KJ3izzEsfeCH0XVidN4tAaMyrd-Jy0i9zwgrD2kzMIrPTonI4oa7IS+Vx3wjyGq83D+KbIiGx3esxK60DJMs4qqhg6Kxw0qFHLGqqJv21zq309KdQWrL2pIoC1p6qTqMzMrxwO3bpWO1DatQddqvq1SQ28vDWupV4ApW0zxOCsDQvTKC+UdD6GJ+sRDsq1i0dckbptJfjLv0662vBjr7qCx7NsRxoc2RhSfvRz1zpqFK3rOqqcLrbCibB5aGzM36KaKqmaii0aYre5nadSuryowwN2cuv6DL-JaIb58T1oo3rnraV7kql8bvuvTSAZcoG5tB4jANWpNBfh4WdrFvafvep3Ppm-7ypS6t8aakGCMEm6Sbum2QLtyDhboqWRsQ6WTa9tmPY5vTLeykOoYe2HCvtxoGihPX6YNr6ksLz2EuTtBWlT27rYzs0h3Dvrc4FGy3ZR42GfdwGTpdxO8dmusoUt1WOvVzONqF5vhwLjui49nvjbl18k8urnCINEeSLHs0s0bnWmlK6P9sltuVLNheJSXrSV79tfA5jTe223sOs+14884ANhn59T7j12L7dGIPusoq7mzrEOVOlAvxZhgbAuBcCIHByfqHcycMI5T0drHccYhWiUGHNtHB+CvyEMQbHasQ4qhQJIQQ1oRCxCIIAeMH8ZdkKCgHt+YeNcPjP1QdndBdQIpI1-uOIcEhRHiPoZIiRc9ST0MoFIhREiGFGwlKA3GsoWpgL0vNdeW5KAfy4WDfmUILRYI0l+Tud48Ysw0kAlhrElaKxQVdXRexKC0IocQjxNDhx-V5koCyk8BGRRAKY4aGkqh2LIchVodjGFoD+uoyoF0-b4WMZwpB3CAloKbsE0qYS7IxycobEus97GAwrp1IK1dMkvECTnGoWZGgjgKeLfWv8Sk1TKUk98q9nE6PvkZdO9T+FNJqHRVpzsynRPniohywC0p+0QfzO+hkrYmRGbkpp+dJlwWNtAyg8CjkwNIcU1hH99Efyudcm51zlGlIlPc6+-ctFoGWeJAZazH5ZK1k9Y82yhS7Pbj-GZ3c5nuXljfYGPDIbKz8rUskmzqJDgitCIFdNplnNmQ8+Z5SzaVJhYTVx6y6k5ORRFQF3YzGl1BefcFMty4E2cUrbmJLEVkuPCiyJoSqXhJpVisFOKIXLwqZdNJHyanLVWEizlEUv7ooTh04uXSf49JrH7UB-M7FwqDlK7JfDclcvaAqopR1sUqtxWqxqwM-orMlRDaVHKoJcpgia9ptLgzxPjoyv2mj0kBzWWnWuMrnURQmbywp7qBV0qFQyhWftbUa3taTfVb8oJiFzjykIfLMVmsFRa4Vzz8VMrriBZNwynV8gzSLLNwio15pjQWuNULcKJrWuW4NlbGjVvlRGtp-KG2evpd6+NwMDGlvfKyoNGyu01GreG7NkaB0Y3zepUuVr2HhkJdqqdhj2UGuohmpoOY3XLsZsqtd3TIWkkcX7A+ziiWDLZY6g9x4j29sXf2xeJ8PUyxxte2UKTgZVD9eJHdxLp2ktfemgUxq+1TJBdGodsaR0trrLUZx4Gn2Qf3WmqtApXXwb2Yhwdf72kbteb9MQH8yadizDUYhHaZ3Qfw00Bddaz1d0bZe1VAHFnQo-tR5xqy-w4ZfXh7tqLa3UtzSu7jiqKMEuE0xqDEm50UukzmkjcnkNNtQ6KpZymA2ib3eJv5MH6iaaXbJ895qeOWr470hNRmdXEz1b8ymkmqgnqI8C3Fv747-pFcWu9Lnd0IrM559TITvDRBAMgFQABrYIygACe5x0hMCQGyJQmA2BsEEJgGgERUCqAKHFi4UA2DAxKAVhgCAYxGBoHAUw6R6m5ZoKkAAqrIOg6RUtcl0HIegsQwgdEwOltI6AdCUhcB0eASATDfBS4ITILWADyKhmuyEwJltg2A2B6CUKtpgLWACCNxsjNVWCdlrAAFRbwMbtrcEGd4QZAYwgGyJoXbcWiuYCu+gAAKp1uAAACAASuoMgOROg4CQDYTmcWAAeKXNDNda+gRLcBUvjcm+kGb1w5tKCQMj2waBZAMFcHF3HiQQDo5ayCfoBQ8cZfQAARwYOof7cQ+iw-+4DkAAA1fIcAAAUABSAAlB0JAZAyBWAoGN1AlPqcBIK2aJrjP0jY9x7l-H6BZCHaJ24KYAEpugDUDcKb+gQAAGIP6xLYzTe3zgvxfg-kKLwHWAdTZAHd742hdDqFGGDgAsnAVQNB8QdGyDDy4KWdDbd2+gPLEQziPbms907ggACiyPLDpAYDgc4Kgxejfq5QW7ggZeeDr+r2Q6PtSgFJ+TunCuAhoDK3AOLvQ4C+BS6EX42P0iqHUBAeHVgduhLr0AA)

If you're looking for dynamic/responsive width (either by setting `"width": "container"` or `"autosize": "fit-x"`), unfortunately I believe vega [doesn't support it for faceted charts](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html#limitations).